# Remove the first instance of '\n' around a string

Tags: php, regex

Hi I have the following situation where I have tags wrapped around my contents and the following input

```
[hello]

Text here

[/hello]

[hello]

Text here 2

[/hello]
```

The output is

```
[hello]\n\nText here\n\n[/hello]\n\n[hello]\n\nText here 2\n\n[/hello]
```

The desired output should be

```
[hello]\nText here\n[/hello][hello]\nText here 2\n[/hello]
```

> PS: THanks for the answer, but since its user input, there's a chance of spacing [hello] \n

Is there a way using php, to trim the first \n around the opening tag ([hello]) and closing tag([/hello])? Thanks

Comment: I generally use `"\n".trim($string)."\n"`

Comment: I don't get it. Please, provide the desired output.

Comment: Thanks Anne, but in this case it'll add the \n even if the output has one \n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's simple, in the other words you want to replace `\n\n` to `\n`

```
$str = "[hello]\n\nText here\n\n[/hello]\n\n[hello]\n\nText here 2\n\n[/hello]";
echo str_replace("\n\n", "\n", $str);
```

it will output

```
[hello]
Text here
[/hello]
[hello]
Text here 2
[/hello]
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple, Try This:

```
$str = "[hello]\n\nText here\n\n[/hello]\n\n[hello]\n\nText here 2\n\n[/hello]";
echo str_replace("[hello]\n","[hello]", str_replace("\n[/hello]","[/hello]",$str));
```

Comment: Hi, if there are spaces eg. [hello] \n will the \n still be removed?

Comment: No, if you are not sure wether it includes a space or not then try replacing `\n\n` to `\n`